# Set file retention policy at container. Azure Storage

Tags: azure-storage

Does Azure Storage supports to set retention policies for *files* that are inside a container ?

I want to set a policy at my Azure Container to delete file if it is 2 days old. 
I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38924157/4481562) post but wanted to make sure if this feature is available now.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> wanted to make sure if this feature is available now.

As I know, this feature is still not support at currently. For this scenario, you need to achieve it by yourself. Please consider what Gaurav Mantri said. If you just want to restrict others to access your resource, please try to consider [SAS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-2).

Comment: Thanks Jambor for great idea of SAS.